# Prevent users from editing folders in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-office-365, exchange-2016, outlook-2016

I would like to know if there is a option to prevent users from editing and reading specified folders in outlook 2016.
I'm using Office 365 business premium, including Share-point and Exchange server.

The situation is as below:
We have one e-mail address for several users. (example@company.eu.)
If someone send a e-mail to user1, user2 or user3 it will be received by this mail account. (The users don't have a separate account, but share one O365-account)

If a email is received i check the e-mail header, if it's containing one of the users e-mail address like (user1@company.eu). The e-mail will be sent to user1's folder.

This is all working with some simple rules set.

Now i want to prevent all users from changing the name of those folders because this can break the rules. 
Also it would be great if the different users can't read the email from the other users.

Do someone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is solved by purchasing mailboxes for each user. I can only assume that this is an attempt to save money, but the time spent managing it will likely negate that.

That being said, if they are all authenticating as the same user, I don't see how you could restrict the access. They all have the same rights, because they are all the same user. This setup could quite possibly be in violation of the terms of service, as Office 365 is licensed per-user, and not per-mailbox.

Comment: Thx for your answer, then unfortunately it seems like there is no easy option to apply this.

It's not useful to add multiple accounts on a computer what only is used for viewing a few files a few times per week. It's to inconvenient for the users to log in and out all the time to view a file or read one e-mail per week.

So i was hoping i can make it easy for them by just open one file viewer and one outlook account where they only had to click on their folder to read their message. 

Perhaps there is some other way to do this?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the more information about the situation and what your are trying to do, the better answers that you will get. We have shared mailboxes here for similar situations, but I can't think of any good ideas on the separation issue, other than your "workaround" that is in place. The casual staff issue here usually gets covered by web mail and an individual account.

Comment: `changing the name of those folders because this can break the rules.` Rules are usually no name-bound, but ID bound. You can change the name of folders and rules will still apply.